# Micro SD impossible to modify (write or format)

Tags: linux, sd-card, dev

Recently i had problems with my SD card used for my android device, basically i cannot modify it (write or format). Only read it, if i try format or write, any time that connect and fisconnect from the smarphone it returned to a initial state.

I have tried differents tools from linux as fdisk and dosfsck, but when i re-connect all return to the same state.

fdisk -l:

Identificador de disco = 0x0000000

(not entries for partition)

dosfsck:

There are differences between 
boot sector and backup.

65:01/00

I dont reach to format it in any way, any suggestion??

Thank you a lot.

Comment: It seems as though the write-protect tab has been shifted to the protect position (away from the contacts). It may be that the tab is damaged, or maybe the write-protect detector in the reader is faulty: if the reader is at fault other SD cards will be equally unwritable, but this SD should be OK in a different reader.

Comment: Other SD cards are readable, micro-sd have no physical lock system if is that you are refering to...

Comment: You didn't say it was a micro-SD, which I know know has no lock, though SD adapters have it, so if you were using one of those to connect to a PC the same comments apply.

Comment: In fact was a usb-connection to my PC using my usb adapter for the smartphone, the micro-SD is inside it and i use the usb adapter.

Comment: OK. Sorry I cannot help. I hope you have success with the HP formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try HP Disk Format Utility, This little tool may solve your problem. I've used it many times and it successfully format my corrupt and protected memory cards.

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/bsc-271/94269/1/SP27608.zip